# Javascript Scope - including without passing or making global

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, scope

I'm working on some script for a set of functions that all operate from one call and take a large number of parameters to return one value. The main function requires the use of 11 other functions which need to work with the same parameters. I have it structured somewhat like this:

```
function mainfunction(param1, param2, ..., param16)
{
    //do a bunch of stuff with the parameters
    return output;
}

function secondaryfunction1()
{
    //gets called by mainfunction
    //does a bunch of stuff with the parameters from mainfunction
}
```

Is there anything I can do to make the parameters passed to mainfunction available to all the secondary functions without passing them or making them global variables? If not, that's fine, I'll pass them as parameters - I'm curious as to whether or not I can do it more elegantly.

Comment: Good question. Caused some healthy debate. +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place the definition of `secondaryfunction1` inside `mainfunction`:

```
function mainfunction(param1, param2, ..., param16){
    function secondaryfunction1() {
     // use param1, param2, ..., param16
    }
    secondaryfunction1();
}
```

**Update:**

As @dystroy pointed out, this is viable if you don't need to call `secondaryfunction1` somewhere else. Where the list of parameters would be coming from in this case - I don't know.

Comment: Having private methods (functions defined inside the 'main function') is definitely the correct way to go on this. Variables are scoped to functions in JavaScript so anything defined in `mainFunction` will be available to all of the private methods.

Comment: If he needed to use the function elsewhere I would still probably follow this pattern and just use `bind` to create an instance of the external function that uses the same `this` scope as `mainFunction`.

Comment: @dystroy - yes, you are right. I should have mentioned it. Will add.

Comment: @pseudosavant I see no conceptual difference to @dystroy's suggestion. I'd say that `bind` is an inelegant way to pass an object as an argument.

Comment: He'd only have to use bind if he was using an external function that is designed to be used by other parts of his application. If all of the functions used need all of the same parameters it seems like it'd make the most sense to create an object that has public methods that could be invoked. That way the state is consistent for all of the functions 'automatically'.

Comment: In this particular case, it is true that the secondary functions are not called elsewhere, so this is the response that I'll be working with. Based on the structure you provided, I imagine I need to define the secondary functions before calling them in this case because they cannot be defined at parse time?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to pass to `secondaryFunction1` all the arguments of `mainfunction`. But that would be silly.

What you should probably do, and what is usually done, is embed all the parameters in an "options" object :

```
function mainfunction(options){
    secondaryfunction1(options);
}

function secondaryfunction1(options) {
     // use options.param1, etc.
}

// let's call it
mainfunction({param1: 0, param2: "yes?"});
```

This leds to other advantages, like

- naming the parameters you pass, it's not a good thing for maintenance to have to count the parameters to know which one to change. No sane library would let you pass 16 parameters as direct unnamed arguments to a function
- enabling you to pass only the needed parameters (the other ones being default)

Comment: @pseudosavant This **is** the usual and right solution. You may find it for example in all jQuery functions which need a lot of parameters.

Comment: @dystroy I'd be hesitant to call something "right" because of it's ubiquity in jQuery ...

Comment: @svidgen I was only giving an example. Do you know a library which lets you pass 16 parameters as direct arguments (YourCorporateHell lib doesn't count) ?

Comment: Not that I disagree with your solution. I do agree that using a parameter object is *almost always* better than an actual parameter list.

Comment: @dystroy to ps' defense, Java often uses that style (or a builder). I think it's because Java lacks a <strike>nice</strike> sensible object literal syntax.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes but in Java you would also use an object, be it as argument or as receiver of the function. You never use call a function with more than 4 or 5 arguments because you can't maintain that.

Comment: @dystroy you do have to create that object at one point, however. That's where the 16-parameter mess or (better, but still ugly syntax) a builder comes in.

Comment: @dystroy I'm not disagreeing with using an object for parameters. I disagree with using a single object to pass parameters around to a half dozen different functions. That is all.

Comment: @pseudosavant Javascript has anonymous/classless objects. Define "single object".

Comment: @JanDvorak by single object I mean this: var opts = { abc: 123 }; function a(opts); function b(opts); function c(opts); function d(opts); If you have to consistent repeat yourself by passing in the same object over and over to each function then they should probably be methods of an object that would maintain that context.

Comment: @pseudosavant noted. Where in the answer does Dystroy actually suggest that practice?

Comment: Nope, my mistake. I misread his example a little. I still think it is a bad practice to have *many* functions all take the same rather complex set of arguments and to not combine them into an object that has methods. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

@Igor 's answer (or some variation) is the way to go. If you have to use the functions elsewhere, though (as @dystroy pointed out), then there is another possibility. Combine your parameters together into an object, and pass that object to the secondary functions.

```
function combineEm() {
    // Get all parameters into an array.
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0),
        output = {},
        i;
    // Now put them in an object
    for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        output["param" + i] = args[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

From your main function, you can do:

```
function mainfunction(param1, param2, ..., param16) {
    var params = combineEm(param1, param2, ..., param16);
    var output = secondaryfunction(params);
    // etc.
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Whether or not an object is used, `arguments` is used, or individual parameters are used is really not the heart of this question I think. I think it is more about scoping and how to access and pass around variables within a function context.

Comment: @pseudosavant To me, he's asking about avoiding passing 16 parameters to 11 functions. This answer requires you to pass those parameters to 1 function, and then the object to the 11 functions. So it does accomplish what he's looking to do. In any case, I do agree that Igor's answer is better, especially with regards to scoping.

Comment: I guess to me I read the OPs question as how to avoid repeatedly passing 16 parameters to 11 functions. He already knows how to repeatedly pass the parameters to a bunch of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just wanted to clarify that all of the proposed suggestions so far do work. They just each have their own trade-offs/benefits.

I tried just suggesting some changes to other answers, but ultimately I felt like I needed to just post my solution to this.

```
var externalFn = function(options) {
  var str = options.str || 'hello world';

  alert(str);
};

var main = function(options) {
  var privateMethod = function() {
    var str = options.str || "foobar";

    alert("str: " + str);
  };

  // Bind a private version of an external function
        var privateMethodFromExternal = externalFn.bind(this, options);

  privateMethod();
  privateMethodFromExternal();
};

main({ str: "abc123"});
// alerts 'str: abc123'
// alerts 'abc123'
main({});
// alerts 'str: foobar'
// alerts 'hello world'
```

- It seems like the main point of the question is that the functions used by the 'main function' shouldn't have to keep having the options/context passed to them.
- This example shows how you can use privateMethods inside the function
- It also shows how you can take external functions (that you presumably use outside of `main`) and bind a private method version of them for use inside `main`.
- I prefer using some sort of 'options' object, but that aspect isn't really that important to the question of scoping that the OP was really asking about. You could use 'regular' parameters as well.

[This example can be found on codepen](http://codepen.io/pseudosavant/pen/GgHLt).

Comment: Downvote without a comment? How am I going to know why my solution was incorrect? :P

Comment: +1 for another perspective with a working answer. Does this scale to 16 parameters and 11 functions? Also, I don't want to speak for the OP, but it may be too advanced for what he's trying to accomplish (it's certainly too advanced for me).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an incredibly naughty solution, if you're interested in that sort of thing.

```
var f1 = function() {
  var a = 1;
  var _f2 = f2.toString().replace(/^function[^{}]+{/, '');
  _f2 = _f2.substr(0, _f2.length - 2);
  eval(_f2);
}

var f2 = function(a) {
  var a = a || 0;
  console.log(a);
}

f2();   // logs 0
f1();   // logs 1
```

It executes the *contents of* some external function entirely in the current scope.

**However**, this sort of trickery is almost definitely an indicator that your project is mis-organized. Calling external functions should *usually* be no more difficult than passing an object around, as **dystroy's answer** suggests, defining the function in-scope, as **Igor's answer** suggests, or by attaching some external function to `this` and writing your functions primarily against the properties of `this`. Like so:

```
var FunLib = {
  a : 0,
  do : function() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}

var Class = function() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.do = FunLib.do;
  this.somethingThatDependsOnDo = function() {
    this.a++;
    this.do();
  }
}

var o = new Class();

FunLib.do()                     // 0
o.do()                          // 1
o.somethingThatDependsOnDo();   // 2
o.do()                          // 2 now
```

Similarly, and possibly *better*-solved with a class hierarchy.

```
function BasicShoe {
  this.steps_taken = 0;
  this.max_steps = 100000;

  this.doStep = function() {
    this.steps_taken++;
    if (this.steps_taken > this.max_steps) {
      throw new Exception("Broken Shoe!");
    }
  }
}

function Boot {
  this.max_steps = 150000;
  this.kick_step_equivalent = 10;

  this.doKick = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.kick_step_equivalent; i++) {
      this.doStep();
    }
  }
}
Boot.prototype = new BasicShoe();

function SteelTippedBoot {
  this.max_steps = 175000;
  this.kick_step_equivalent = 0;
}
SteelTippedBoot.prototype = new Boot();
```